# Get categories with number of hits (entries, products)

Tags: categories, performance

Is there a way to get a list of categories with the number of entries associated with each particular category?

I want to output something like this:

[image: number of hits per category]

It would make sense to fetch the number of hits in the same DB query. But currently I get the hits by running a `craft.products(itemParams).total()` per category iteration.

Or is this not a real performance problem?

Comment: I'm guessing these totals will change depending on filters, so caching's not an option?

Comment: Yup, but I am using query string parameters, so each unique filter combination is cacheable. Am using caching now. Just asking more out of curiosity as to whether I can do these kinds of queries.

Comment: Do you have multiple categories per products?

Comment: Yes, and multiple product types